# How can I implement html views for django-oauth-toolkit?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-oauth

I am following the basic tutorial in [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_01.html) . Do I have to create the html files for the views (eg login.html, loggout.html)? My thought is that there is a default "out of the box implementation" for these files.

I get the following error when I try to access oauth2 urls:

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\registration\login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ...\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\registration\login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templates\registration\login.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ...\lib\site-packages\oauth2_provider\templates\registration\login.html (Source does not exist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the documentation on [the site](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/rest-framework.html) is deprecated. The updated documents have not been published to digital ocean. But you can navigate them from github directly - [view on github](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/docs/rest-framework/rest-framework.rst)